# Debugging Visual Studio Extension Performance Issues

Tags: visual-studio-2010, resharper

How do I figure out which extension(s) are killing VS 2010 editing perf?

I am running the following extensions in VS:

- Block Tagger
- Collapse Solution
- Highlight all occurrences of selected word
- PowerCommands
- Productivity Power Tools
- VS!0x Code Map
- VS10x Method Block Highlighter
- VSCommands 2010
- Resharper

I love the functionality, but the performance gets really bad (1 second delays in typing) and I end up flipping everything off (except resharper).

Is there a **tool** that can narrow down where the cycles are being spent when I am editing a file? It is probably a certain combination that is doing it.

Answer (score 3):

codemap has a history of poor performance with files > 100 lines of code.
Try disabling and see if it gets any better.

Sometimes extensions may have compatibility issues with each other, so you have to try different combinations

Answer (score 1):

Try launching VS under a performance profiler: for example, [dotTrace Performance](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/). Not free but the tool provides a 10-day free trial that should allow you to at least get preliminary results of performance analysis and see which of the VS extension takes most resources.

That said, having 9 extensions in VS is a lot, ridiculously lot. Your Visual Studio must be crying.

By the way, are you really sure you need all these extensions? For instance, ReSharper provides "[Highlight usages](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Navigation_and_Search__Finding_Usages__Highlighting_Usages_in_File.html)" command that sets highlights both in the text editor and in ReSharper marker bar, and you can browse up and down the usages with a shortcut. Does it not render "Highlight all occurrences of selected word" redundant?